# reconnect to database or use old connection for better perfomance

Tags: php, performance, class, extends

I have multiple classes, and all connecting to the same database I have my database class and user, profile, message class?
should I use extends or just just global and get the old connection, for speed and performance

```
class mydb{
function connect(){
}
function query(){
}
}
$mydb = new mydb(connect);




    class user extends mydb{
    function get_usr(){
    parent::connect(); // in here I need to connect again, but I still have my connection $mydb
    $value = parent::query(string);
    return $value;
        }
```

Or

```
class user{
function get_usr(){
global $mydb;
$value = $mydb->query(string);
return $value
}

}
```

now which one is better for better performance .

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Best practice for enterprise applications is create a pool of connections to Database. These connections are always open from DB side.

Whenever application or your class needs to communnicate with DB then class pick up one connection from pool (which should be configurable) and use it. This saves time for connection establishment and disconnection. But its developers responsibility to release the connection after usage back to connection pool.

This helps in,

1. keeping DB server utilization within limits
2. Improving performance of DB
3. limiting no. of queries hitting to DB
4. Improving code readability and re-usability.

From performance point of view, not only DB connection pool is important but also type of statements you use is also important. it is advised to use prepared statements while using connection pool to improve performance.

Answer (score 1):

Closing an reconnecting takes time (in ms).
It is best to use one global connection (opened) all the time.
This is best practices in all programming languages.

PS: Don't forget to close the connection when it's not needed (like when the user it's closing the software) :)